# Animation with colormap in python

Tags: python

I made a small program in Fortran to generate a matrix of rank n whose elements are random number between 0 and 9, with each iteration, change the matrix elements, I want to assign each color number and show an animation with map colors.
For example:
for t = 5    a[5 6]= 5 and 5 = "red"

for t = 9    a[5 6]= 7 and 7 = "blue"

some ideas? and in three dimension would be similar?
Thank you!

Comment: for python, probably look at matplotlib, but your problem is not very clearly described (What is `a[5 6]`? a pixel location or time point or ?)

Comment: Sorry, a[5 6] is a pixel location